# Sculpting tool is not working at all

Tags: sculpting

The sculpting tool is not working at all – even on the default cube on a new project. I loaded factory settings, but it is still not working. It was working a while ago, but now it's not working anymore. I might have pressed some wrong shortcut or something? Any ideas?

System Information:

- Operating system: macOS Catalina 10.15.1
- Graphics card: Radeon pro Vega 48 8 GB
- Blender Version

Comment: It seems you forgot to add your Blender version.

Comment: It's probably not possible to tell what's wrong with sculpting in your case, but default cube won't be quite available for adding details with this way. Make sure there's any geometry

Answer (score 1):

To effectively use Blender's sculpting tool, you must first subdivide the object you are trying to sculpt. Sculpting moves a certain section of vertices on an object where you use the tool, so if there are no vertices to move, you cannot sculpt the object. To subdivide, go to edit mode, press 'W', and set the amount of subdivisions to be about 60 for effective sculpting.